# Treat Xsd Xml Validation Warning as Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd, xml-validation

I found that in Project Properties, there is an option to Treat Selected Warnings as Error in VS 2010. And What is the way to specify an Xml Warning obtained by Validating it against an Xsd as Error ?  Since i want Validation to occur during Build i am Not using ValidationEventHandler to validate Xml. Any other Suggestion will also  be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a VS setting to do that, you need to add a custom build step that validates the XML files against their schemas explicitly.